# jQuery comma separated string to object map

Tags: javascript, jquery

After long hours of work I figured out how to get my ajax value. It looks like this:

> 37,58,82,

I managed out how to remove last comma and make array like this:

```
Object { 0="37", 1="58", 2="82"}
```

But I need it to be like this (according to firebug):

```
[Object { trackID="track-id-37"}, Object { trackID="track-id-58"}, Object { trackID="track-id-58"},]
```

How can I make it to look like?

Comment: What code did you use to transform `37,58,82,` into `Object { 0="37", 1="58", 2="82"}`?

Comment: @Nightfirecat I used
`tracks = $.extend({}, tracks);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. If you have your array, you can call $.map on it.

```
$.map(["37", "58", "82"], function(elem) { return { trackID: "track-id-" + elem }; });
```

Or let's say your string is called your_string...we can act directly on it (I've added whitespace to make it clear what's going on)--

```
your_string = '37,58,82,';
$.map(your_string.split(','), function(elem) 
                              { 
                                if (elem != '') 
                                { 
                                   return { trackID: "track-id-" + elem }; 
                                } 
                              });
```

The `if (elem != '')` statement is to protect against any empty array values after the `split(',')`. `$.map` tolerates return values of `undefined`.

Also consider using $.trim on elem in order to build in tolerance for spaces and so on, e.g.

```
$.map(your_string.split(','), function(elem) 
                              { 
                                var id = $.trim(elem);
                                if (id != '') 
                                { 
                                   return { trackID: "track-id-" + id }; 
                                } 
                              });
```